# Maximise the number of nodes with degree zero in a bipartite graph

Tags: bipartite-graphs, matching-theory

Let $G = (V \cup W, E)$ be a bipartite graph where $V \cap W = \emptyset$ and $E$ consists of edges between nodes in $V$ and $W$. All nodes in $W$ must have degree at least one whereas nodes in $V$ are allowed to have any degree (including zero). I want to assign/dedicate each node in $W$ to a specific node in $V$; i.e prune the edges such that $deg(w) = 1$ for all nodes in $W$. However, I want to do it in such a way, that as many nodes in $V$ ends up having degree zero.

As I see it, it is somewhat the "reverse problem" to that of a maximal matching problem. I haven't been able to find any similar questions nor can I figure out if it is a NP hard problem. The closest I have been to track down a similar problem is

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20051303/optimization-of-bipartite-graph

which is not exactly what is my case.

Comment: Do I understand correctly that the nodes in $V$ can have any degree? I believe that that sentence lacks a word.

Comment: Yes that is correct. Just edited. Thx.

Comment: Have you tried the greedy algorithm? Take the node in $V$ with the highest degree, use all those edges. Then remove all used nodes and their edges from the graph, and repeat on the resulting subgraph. Does that always work? If not, when does it fall to give the optimal result?

Comment: Thanks @Arthur for the suggestion. That's exactly what I was planning to implement. I was just curious if there was any known algorithm that would always find an optimum.

Comment: Put differently, you have  a collection of subsets $A_v\subseteq W$ (namely, for each $v\in V$ the set of its neighbours) such that $\bigcup_v A_v=W$ , and you want to select a minimal subcover

Comment: Great way to put it! However, I'm not sure if you suggest that this could lead to another heuristic or some other solution?

Comment: @Hage von Eitzen You let me to this:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_cover_problem

which is perfect! Thanks.